# NullPointerException for Radiogroup

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, radio-button, radio-group

I try to make a quiz app. I need to know which radiobutton has been chosen and check that with the real correct answer. I send the trueResult(score var.) to another ResultActivity class if it is need to be known.

```
    if(((RadioButton) grp_options.getChildAt(grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().equals(rightAnswers.get(i))) // Error at this expression
    {
        trueResult++;
    }
```

When i change the part below

> `grp_options.getChildAt(grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId()))`

to this

> `grp_options.getChildAt(3))`

it properly compares the 4th option with the real answer. But i need to learn which rb user checked. So the problem is here :

> `grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`

After all, the app gives me NPE. Here is the log. If there is a better way to do this job or a point i am missing, i would love to learn.

Comment: This is the NPE log.
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10991859/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCheckedRadioButtonId` returns the view id, ie. the `android:id`.

If you have set the ids in the layout, you should be able to retrieve the element with `findViewById`:

```
grp_options.findViewById(grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
```

Comment: do you have the id for each radio button set in your layout?

Comment: Yes. rdb_optionA ,b,c and d

Comment: Does an item have to be selected in order to reach this block of code? What do you get if you log `grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`?

Comment: Solved with anoter way. Thanks for help i appreciate :)
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10992464/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure, but you might try this:

Instead of this:

```
if(((RadioButton) grp_options.getChildAt(grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().equals(rightAnswers.get(i)))
```

try this:

```
if(((RadioButton) findViewById(grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString().equals(rightAnswers.get(i)))
```

I think your problem might be that you forgot to use `toString()` in your solution, maybe this works fine too:

```
if(((RadioButton) grp_options.getChildAt(grp_options.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString().equals(rightAnswers.get(i)))
```

Comment: Just a simple question. The 'rightAnswers' is an object, right? Do you are initializing  before to call the .get() method?

Comment: Thanks man for your time. ;) Solved it but with a spaghetti code.http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10992464/

Comment: But i would be so happy if i learn what is initializing a variable